# laravel: Get sum of orders table by month

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am trying to tot up the total orders by month for use in a chart. I am having difficulty get this to work out.

I'm trying to figure out a foreach that will return all months in a year with a value of `0` if there isn't a `sum()` for the month.

Added to this, I want to make this work for last year and this year too.

Any pointers as the right way to go? Thanks in advance for taking the time to help out.

Currently I have the following:

```
$all_this_year = Payments::all()->groupBy(function($date) {
                                     return Carbon::parse($date->created_at)->format('F');
                                 });
```

Which is giving me this:

```
object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)[1635]
  protected 'items' => 
   array (size=2)
     'September' => 
      array (size=4)
      0 => 
        object(Models\Payments)[1626]
          ...
      1 => 
        object(Models\Payments)[1628]
          ...
      2 => 
        object(Models\Payments)[1637]
          ...
      3 => 
        object(Models\Payments)[1640]
          ...
     'October' => 
      array (size=4)
      0 => 
        object(Models\Payments)[1638]
          ...
      1 => 
        object(Models\Payments)[1639]
          ...
      2 => 
        object(Models\Payments)[1641]
          ...
      3 => 
        object(Models\Payments)[1642]
          ...
```

Comment: Why don't you do that in the db query?

Comment: Yeah, I think I might have to go down that route. I am trying to limit queries. I'll have a play. Cheers.

Comment: A DB query will give you much better performance

Comment: @T2theC Limit queries when needed but don't do this kind of stuff with php objects, this will not be better in terms of performance.